# how to fix "ImportError: cannot import name label_map_util"

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

Upon doing

```
from utils import label_map_util
```

I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name label_map_util
```

Changing to

```
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
```

gives the same error.

I'm trying with PyCharm on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `pycharm` terminal change current directory to `models/research` and run the following command

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```